# Jquery Multiple togglefade

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following code to create pop up boxes

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.item-link').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#pop-up-' + id).fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.pop-up{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="1" class="item-link">
Link 1
</a>
<a href="#" id="2" class="item-link">
Link 2
</a>
<a href="#" id="3" class="item-link">
Link 3
</a>
<a href="#" id="4" class="item-link">
Link 4
</a>

<div class="pop-up" id="pop-up-1">
Content 1
</div>
<div class="pop-up" id="pop-up-2">
Content 2
</div>
<div class="pop-up" id="pop-up-3">
Content 3
</div>
<div class="pop-up" id="pop-up-4">
Content 4
</div>
```

It works fine, but I would like to closed the pop up when another link is click or click anywhere else on the page. I'm not that great with jquery

Comment: Please don't link to 3rd party sites as those links can become broken over time. Post your code, right here in a code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to close any pop ups when the user clicks anywhere on the page, you need to capture the click event at a higher level than the links themselves which relies on events "bubbling" up from the original target to the `document` or `window`. This way, you can react to clicks that occur anywhere in the document.

---

Additionally, don't use `<a>` elements when you aren't actually navigating anywhere. Just about any element can be given a `click` event handler, so use the best elements for your content. The added benefit is that you don't have to cancel (with `e.preventDefault()`) the native behavior of clicking on, say a `span` like you do with an `a` because there is no native click behavior of a `span`.

Lastly, as a best-practice, you should not give elements `id` values that start with a number.

From **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)**:

> Note: Using characters except ASCII letters, digits, '_', '-' and '.'
>   may cause compatibility problems, as they weren't allowed in HTML 4.
>   Though this restriction has been lifted in HTML 5, an ID should start
>   with a letter for compatibility.

See comments inline below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Catch all clicks, no matter where they originated
  $(document).on("click", function(e){
    
    $(".pop-up").hide("slow");  // Hide all the pop ups
  
    // Show just the one that was requested. The event target (e.target here)
    // represents the actual object that the event originated from.
    $("#pop-up-" + e.target.id).show("slow");
  
  });

});
```

```css
/* Make the span elements look/feel like links: */
.item-link {
  cursor:pointer;
  text-decoration:underline;
  color:blue;
}

.pop-up{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="a" class="item-link">Link 1</span> |
<span id="b" class="item-link">Link 2</span> |
<span id="c" class="item-link">Link 3</span> |
<span id="d" class="item-link">Link 4</span>

<div class="pop-up" id="pop-up-a">Content 1</div>
<div class="pop-up" id="pop-up-b">Content 2</div>
<div class="pop-up" id="pop-up-c">Content 3</div>
<div class="pop-up" id="pop-up-d">Content 4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    
    function fn_click(obj){
      $(obj).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#pop-up-' + id).fadeToggle();
      });
    }

    function fn_blur(obj){
       $('.item-link').on('blur',function(e){
          $('.item-link').hide();
        
       });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <a href="#" id="1" onClick="fn_click(this);" onBlur="fn_blur(this);" class="item-link">
  Link 1
  </a>
  <a href="#" id="2" onClick="fn_click(this);" onBlur="fn_blur(this);" class="item-link">
  Link 2
  </a>
  <a href="#" id="3" onClick="fn_click(this);" onBlur="fn_blur(this);" class="item-link">
  Link 3
  </a>
  <a href="#" id="4" onClick="fn_click(this);" onBlur="fn_blur(this);" class="item-link">
  Link 4
  </a>

  <div class="pop-up" id="pop-up-1">
  Content 1
  </div>
  <div class="pop-up" id="pop-up-2">
  Content 2
  </div>
  <div class="pop-up" id="pop-up-3">
  Content 3
  </div>
  <div class="pop-up" id="pop-up-4">
  Content 4
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add `$('.pop-up').not('#pop-up-' + id).hide()` above your `fadeToggle()` and that will close the others before opening a new one while still fading out if the current one is clicked again

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.item-link').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.pop-up').not('#pop-up-' + id).hide();
    $('#pop-up-' + id).fadeToggle();
  });

$(document).click(function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).is('.pop-up')) {
        if($('.pop-up').is(':visible')) {
            $('.pop-up').fadeOut();
        }
    }
})
});
```

```css
.pop-up{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="1" class="item-link">
Link 1
</a>
<a href="#" id="2" class="item-link">
Link 2
</a>
<a href="#" id="3" class="item-link">
Link 3
</a>
<a href="#" id="4" class="item-link">
Link 4
</a>

<div class="pop-up" id="pop-up-1">
Content 1
</div>
<div class="pop-up" id="pop-up-2">
Content 2
</div>
<div class="pop-up" id="pop-up-3">
Content 3
</div>
<div class="pop-up" id="pop-up-4">
Content 4
</div>
```

Comment: Your code do not have for hide the popup if anywhere click on page ? 
are you sure it will work ?

Comment: Don't post links to 3rd party sites. There's no reason you can't post that code in a code snippet here.

Comment: @vjytiwari You are right, i edited the snippet that Scott Marcus graciously created

Comment: Ok, it works, but why 2 convoluted functions when one simple one will do?

Comment: @ScottMarcus mostly for code separation, this will provide for better flexibility in the future if more clicks on the document need delt with,  but I agree, for this one simple problem a simpler solution is possible

Answer (score -2):

You can close all the popups and show the required one -

```
<script>
    $('.item-link').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        // Hide every pop up
        $(".pop-up").each(function()){ $(this).css({'opacity' : 0}); };

        $('#pop-up-' + id).fadeToggle();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That won't help when the user clicks somewhere other than the links. *"I would like to closed the pop up when another link is click **or click anywhere else on the page**"*